# Instances appearing twice when extending signatures

Tags: alloy

When I execute the following example using Alloy, either v4.2 or v5, I get an instance that appear twice in solution space.

```
sig A {}
sig B extends A { }
pred P { }
run P for 2
```

Generated instances:

```
1:A={}, B={}
2:A={A$0}, B={}
3:A={B$0}, B={B$0}
4:A={A$0, B$0}, B={B$0}
5:A={A$0, A$1}, B={}
6:A={A$0, B$0}, B={B$0} // same as instance 4
7:A={B$0, B$1}, B={B$0, B$1}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a different scope for each signature
for example:

> run P for 2 A, 4 B